# How to remove space from print statement in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm printing a simple line program in Python. But when I add a period after a comma in the print statement, I keep seeing a space in between the end of the result and the period.
How can I remove this space with a simple print statement?

Code:

```
print("The sum of 1-9 is",1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9,".")
```

Result:

```
The sum of 1-9 is 45 .
```

Desired result:

```
The sum of 1-9 is 45.
```

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should get accustomed to using python's [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). You could use an f-string to print this statement like this:

```py
print(f"The sum of 1-9 is {1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9}.")
```

The f-string setup will just replace whatever is between the `{}` with the expression - in this case, it'll do the sum and result in a single number. You can also put in a variable name or any other expression.

Comment: Thank you! From now on, I'll start using f-strings from now on. They seem like a better option than simple print statements.

Comment: @ArchitChawla, you can use them any time you are working with formatting strings, not just when it comes to the final print. For example, you could have `my_string = f"1+2 is {1+2}"`, and this will create the new string called my_string which will have a value of "1+2 is 3". You can then later do `print(my_string)`, but you can also do any other string functions on it or whatever else your heart can imagine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use string formatting:

```py
print("The sum of 1-9 is %s." % str(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9))
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I would advise to use an f-string, as said by the other answer, you can use the `sep` key-word argument to remove the spaces

```
print("The sum of 1-9 is ",1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9,".", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `,` between the print arguments adds a space.

You can use string concatenation to remove this additional space:

```
print("The sum of 1-9 is", str(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9) + ".")
```

Or better yet, try using `f-strings`:

```
print(f"The sum of 1-9 is {1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9}.")
```